# Term list limits for text index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, full-text-indexing

I am facing the *"term list limits for text index"* issue with one of my collections. As of version 4.0.8 (Release), this limit is set to 400,000 or 4MB, but according to [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22078) the issue has been resolved in the dev version 4.1.2.

My question is, is it worth upgrading my mongodb server version 4.0.8 with currently available dev version 4.1.9 or should I try to find another solution?

Comment: As a general case you probably should avoid asking "Which is best?" or "Which should I choose?" questions here at all. I'll make the exception based on if you have an application "in development" yourself, then I see nothing wrong with using a development release of a service or library as chances are it will also be production ready by the time "your application" is ready for production. If however you are talking about an existing production system, then the answer is **never** use development release libraries or services in your production system.

Comment: You might also consider that *"maybe"* your "text search" usage is probably hitting the limits of what you can reasonably expect from basic implementations found in many database products. If you come up against such limits on a regular basis ( or even need this in production ASAP ) then you probably should consider a dedicated "text search" service. "Text search" in MongoDB or even products like MySQL are really quite *"basic"* by nature. And that's all they really should be.

Comment: Thanks, @NeilLunn. My application is almost production ready, so ill be looking into other options. I really didn't know where to ask this question, ill be careful next time.

Comment: What I was basically saying it that it *just barely* scrapes within the rules of otherwise being an opinion based question. It still *technically* would be, but I believe it's a reasonably informed consensus that you should not use development libraries or services within a production environment. Of course *"use at your own risk"* applies everywhere, and even with "Production Ready" code and services.